# Can I adjust the height of the grid.column?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

Is there any ways to adjusting the height of the grid.column in xaml?

I want to create a calculator with a wide screen(or textbox) but the issue is when I am using grid.Columndefinitions, it is taking the entire page up. All I wanted is to adjust the columns to the bottom of the first row.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you want the Grid to start where the buttom grid rows start now. To achive this, you can place a stackPanel behind it, and place the grid below a textBox.

Something like this:

```
 <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Height="100"
             Text="TextBox"
             FontSize="70"
             TextAlignment="Right"/>

    <Grid Height="300">

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    </Grid>        

</StackPanel>
```

It is going to need some adjustments to fit your design, but I hope this is what you had in mind.

Comment: Hey that is something definitely what I have in mind.

Comment: if you don't mind me asking. I am looking at the site, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/stack-layout.

if i want to built my calculator properly, do I have to follow the order that which the  layout is set? like example, stack layout first, absolute layout second, relative layout third, and grid last or can I mixed up the layout?

Comment: @Sebastien thoose layouts are completly different ways to go about designing your application, and is not an order of witch to position things. When that is said, you can mix up different styles. For example you can have a stack layout, where your at some point have a grid (like the sample code you got from me).

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible. If you want to do that you need to adjust the height of the `Grid` itself (e.g. using `HeightRequest` or placining it in some layout).